# R caret train glmnet final model lambda values not as specified

Tags: r, machine-learning, package, r-caret

I was using `caret` package to tune a glmnet logistic regression model. While the `lambda` value from best tune is one of the values I specified in the `tuneGrid`, the `lambda` values of the final model are totally different:

```
require(caret)
set.seed(1)
x <- matrix(runif(1000), nrow = 100)
y <- factor(rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))
lambda.seq <- exp(seq(log(1e-5), log(1e0), length.out = 20))

model <- train(x, y, 
               method ="glmnet", 
               family = "binomial", 
               tuneGrid = expand.grid(alpha = 1, 
                                      lambda = lambda.seq))
model$bestTune
#    alpha    lambda
# 13     1 0.0143845
model$finalModel$lambdaOpt
# [1] 0.0143845

model$finalModel$lambda
#  [1] 0.1236344527 0.1126511087 0.1026434947 0.0935249295 0.0852164325 0.0776460395
#  [7] 0.0707481794 0.0644631061 0.0587363814 0.0535184032 0.0487639757 0.0444319185
# [13] 0.0404847094 0.0368881594 0.0336111170 0.0306251980 0.0279045398 0.0254255774
# [19] 0.0231668392 0.0211087610 0.0192335169 0.0175248642 0.0159680036 0.0145494502
# [25] 0.0132569171 0.0120792091 0.0110061255 0.0100283716 0.0091374787 0.0083257303
# [31] 0.0075860954 0.0069121676 0.0062981097 0.0057386030 0.0052288013 0.0047642890
# [37] 0.0043410427 0.0039553964 0.0036040099 0.0032838396 0.0029921123 0.0027263013
# [43] 0.0024841042 0.0022634233 0.0020623470 0.0018791337 0.0017121967 0.0015600899
# [49] 0.0014214958 0.0012952140 0.0011801508 0.0010753094 0.0009797819 0.0008927408

model$finalModel$lambdaOpt %in% lambda.seq
# [1] TRUE
```

The final model's optimal value of `lambda` is also not in the list of `lambda` that the same model supposedly used:

```
model$finalModel$lambdaOpt %in% model$finalModel$lambda
# [1] FALSE
```

What explains these discrepancies in `lambda`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The final model is basically a refit with your **whole** dataset AFTER `alpha` and `lambda` were optimized using resampling techniques.

If you print `model$finalModel$call` you see the call being made (omitted x, y structure for shortness):

```
    Call:  glmnet(x, y, family = "binomial", alpha = 1)
```

Here, `alpha` is set (if you had set a sequence it would be the optimum `alpha` found), but no specified lambda is set to train, and therefore an automatic sequence is generated based on your data and the model is fitted. It then predicts with the same training set with `lambdaOpt` (and the rest of the sequence you gave). Take a look at [glmnet vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/Papers/Glmnet_Vignette.pdf) and how you can specify different `lambda` after training.

If you type:

```
    > names(model$modelInfo)
     [1] "label" "library" "type" "parameters" "grid" "loop"       
     [7] "fit" "predict" "prob" "predictors" "varImp" "levels"    
     [13] "tags" "sort" "trim"
```

and then walk through each of those sections, you can take a look at what `train`is doing. You can see in `model$modelInfo$predict` how it predicts on `lambdaOpt` and the rest of your sequence.

When you print `model$results` you actually get your list of `lambda` and the performance on the **whole** training set with each one:

```
 alpha       lambda  Accuracy      Kappa AccuracySD    KappaSD
1      1 1.000000e-05 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
2      1 1.832981e-05 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
3      1 3.359818e-05 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
4      1 6.158482e-05 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
5      1 1.128838e-04 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
6      1 2.069138e-04 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
7      1 3.792690e-04 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
8      1 6.951928e-04 0.5698940 0.15166891 0.09061320 0.17133524
9      1 1.274275e-03 0.5675708 0.14690433 0.09071728 0.17085665
10     1 2.335721e-03 0.5643334 0.14059590 0.09153010 0.17204036
11     1 4.281332e-03 0.5629588 0.13822063 0.09403553 0.17715441
12     1 7.847600e-03 0.5694974 0.15221600 0.08791315 0.16433922
13     1 1.438450e-02 0.5700431 0.15448347 0.08864353 0.16509332
14     1 2.636651e-02 0.5695053 0.15189752 0.08113581 0.15184619
15     1 4.832930e-02 0.5635977 0.14112303 0.05833646 0.11617226
16     1 8.858668e-02 0.5305835 0.08983718 0.08116759 0.14752307
17     1 1.623777e-01 0.4800871 0.01124082 0.05827521 0.05715298
18     1 2.976351e-01 0.4725241 0.00000000 0.04488500 0.00000000
19     1 5.455595e-01 0.4725241 0.00000000 0.04488500 0.00000000
20     1 1.000000e+00 0.4725241 0.00000000 0.04488500 0.00000000
```

To summarise what's happening in caret+glmnet:

1. optimizes `alpha` and `lambda`within the tuneGrid you provided using resampling techniques;
2. refits the model, now on the **whole** training set, with **optimal** `alpha`;
3. predicts on the whole training set with `lambdaOpt` found in 1. and on the rest of the sequence of lambdas in tuneGrid.